# PowerShell version 1.0 - Write to the event log

Tags: powershell, event-log

We have a client with PowerShell 1.0. I know in PowerShell 2.0, I have the `Write-EventLog` *commandlet*. However, this doesn't appear in PowerShell 1.0. I want my script to log events to the event log, mainly for debugging purposes.

How can I do this with PowerShell 1.0:? And, no I can't upgrade this computer to PowerShell 2.0. This is a customer production machine, and they don't want to touch the software on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .NET EventLog class to do this.  It is pretty simple to use e.g.:

```
$eventSource = "MyAppName"
if (![Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($eventSource))
{
    [Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource($eventSource, "Application")
}

[Diagnostics.EventLog]::WriteEntry($eventSource, "message", [Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Error)
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I was trying to first create an object, but this is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just access the [.NET EventLog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) to write to the log.