# PowerShell Logins and Privs

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

What login does PowerShell run as when called from a PowerShell Task in an SQL Server job?  Apparently my "Google_foo" is weak because I can't find it and I didn't want to just assume that it would run as the login associated with SQL Server Agent.

I'd also like to know if it can be changed and how?

Thanks for your help, folks.

Comment: Heh... most forums say not to explain that you're a rank beginner at something because, based on the question, it'll be obvious. I have no idea how to do what you've suggested which I appreciate very much) or I'd have already done it.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115686/get-current-user-context) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337059/powershell-version-1-0-write-to-the-event-log) for some clues.  (I'm not much of a PowersHell user, but I do think it's one of the best Truth In Advertising product names for Microsoft.)

Comment: No need to write to eventlog. Just setup a SQL Agent job with a Powershell jobstep that runs $env:username

Answer (score 4):

It will run as the SQL Agent account unless you set the job to run under a proxy.

Comment: correct, and here is how to [Create SQL Server Agent Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx)